# Hyper V with Linux guest backups

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Can anyone tell me of which software/method using for backup VM's in Hyper V with VM's running Ubuntu(ver 14.04 kernel 3.19.0-25-generic).

Actually we have this errors, and this cause unmount file system and reboot in Read Only mode !

```
Mar 25 23:04:30 ns1 kernel: [836257.824269] sd 0:0:0:0: [storvsc] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]
Mar 25 23:04:30 ns1 kernel: [836257.824308] sd 0:0:0:0: [storvsc] Add. Sense: Changed operating definition
Mar 25 23:04:30 ns1 kernel: [836257.824389] sd 0:0:0:0: Warning! Received an indication that the operating parameters on this target have changed. The Linux SCSI layer does not automatically adjust these parameters.
Mar 25 23:05:01 ns1 CRON[35998]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 25 23:05:40 ns1 kernel: [836327.552853] sd 0:0:0:0: [storvsc] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]
Mar 25 23:05:40 ns1 kernel: [836327.552873] sd 0:0:0:0: [storvsc] Add. Sense: Changed operating definition
Mar 25 23:05:40 ns1 kernel: [836327.552962] sd 0:0:0:0: Warning! Received an indication that the operating parameters on this target have changed. The Linux SCSI layer does not automatically adjust these parameters.
```

When reboot

```
[1700789.820160] sd 0:0:0:0: Warning! Received an indication that the operating parameters on this target have changed. The Linux SCSI layer does not automatically adjust these parameters.
[1701352.412047] EXT4-fs (sda4): error count since last fsck: 2
[1701352.412062] EXT4-fs (sda4): initial error at time 1458796255: ext4_journal_check_start:56
[1701352.412064] EXT4-fs (sda4): last error at time 1458796255: ext4_journal_check_start:56
```

Thanks !

Comment: You need any suggestion for back up software ?

Comment: no  thanks, i post my problem here finding for a similar person with the same problem and a probably solution